# how to pass android EdiText to PHP, explode it, and pass JSON to android

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli

I am very new to android and I have problem with passing the JSON back to android. I don't know if the problem is with the "thing" in PHP. I actually pass the EditText value which is a string to PHP and explode it. I do some process on the exploded value before passing it to android. but the problem is it keeps on crashing (the app). can someone please help me with this.

this is the code how i pass it to php:(brief codes)

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("my_string", editText));
 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_translate, "GET", params);
```

and this is what happens in php:(brief codes)

```
if (isset($_GET['my_string'])) 
{
    $str=$_GET['my_string'];

    echo "string: $str<br/>";
    $explodestr=explode(" ", $str);
}
```

I have no idea if I can explode that string in php or not it keeps giving the error of:

"Value sentence of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

I highly appreciate help from you guys!!!

Comment: I think you are passing just the edittext view and not the edittext string.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try `editText.getText().toString()` in first line instead of just `editText`.

Passing just `editText` as `View`  won't make a String from it.

You can alsa add `.trim()` to get rid of whitespaces at start and the end of the String.